# How to print an int array into a horizontal arrow?

Tags: java, arrays

Having an array such as `int[] arr = new int[]{9, 6, 5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 3, 8, 1, 5, 4, 7};` I want to print it like this:

```
 * Output:
 * 9
 * 6 1
 * 5 2 2
 * 2 6 7 1
 * 3 3 5
 * 8 4
 * 7
```

Without the * basically that's what I am trying to do. I intended to go over the array and just use `System.out.println();`until I reached then "end" which would be the 7 and then go to the next line but that didn't work.

I also tried printing 9 then 6 and 1 and so on but I couldn't make it to work either, I'm at a loss here and would appreciate guidance as to how can I think this through please.

**EDIT**

The intermediate step I have is making the array a "block" like this:

```
 * Intermediate Step:
 * 9 6 5 2
 * 1 2 6 3
 * 2 7 3 8
 * 1 5 4 7
```

It should work for an array of any size.

Comment: Can you explain how that array gets turned into your desired output?  I don't see a pattern here at all.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish at best I have an intermediate step I'll add in there.

Comment: Did you write the output right corresponding to your sample input? Because after 9,6,5,2 it does not make sense to me.

Comment: There is no working code for me to show hence why I'm lost and @libik it might work after the intermediate step I just added.

Comment: Use `System.out.print(..)` if you want to stay in the same line or create the String for each line before output it with `System.out.println(..)`.

Comment: No @MrSmith42, it's not that. I would've figured that out if it were that simple. Please don't be condescending.

Comment: the first output you posted, doesnt make sense. can you guide us with that? thnx

Comment: Still dont see pattern, for example why "2, 7, 3, 8" is added to these strange positions?

Comment: The pattern works with the intermediate step. You grab the array and make it that "box" after my edit. Then you go rows first then columns so you take 9, 6, 5, 2 /row then 3 8 7 /col and that's the first line in the triangle. then you move to the next row and next col @libik

Comment: @libik the second output is clear. it's divided at every 4 characters. the first is the weird

Comment: @Apostolos, the first output is actually the final goal. I am given an array THEN I transform it into the output under my edit and form there I have to go to the first output I posted. (the triangle). You can see how that's made from my past reply to libik.

Comment: @Luis Armando: Sorry, but it seams I did not get what the problem is than.

Comment: ok got it. i now understood it.

Comment: Yea, I understand that too :)

Comment: @LuisArmando did you check my answer?

Comment: @Apostolos sorry had to log off yesterday. Just did, I commented below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work
You iterate 2 times. first you get the first row and all the diagonal rows below it, and then the last row and all the diagonal rows above it. You have to create a second array though to hold this info. I assumed that the array is same size for both X and Y. 7x7, 4x4 etc. tested with 4x4 data (your data)

```
String[][] array2 = new String[array.length*2][array.length];

for (int mb = 0; mb < array.length; mb++) {
    String p1 = array[0][mb];  

     array2[mb][0] = p1;
     int count = 0;
     for (int i=1;i<=mb;i++) {
         count++;
         String p2 = array[i][mb-i];
         array2[mb][count] = p2;
     }
} 

int counter = -1;
for (int mb = array.length -1; mb > 0; mb--) { 
    counter++;
    String p1 = array[array.length -1][mb];  

    array2[mb+array.length -1][counter] = p1;
    for (int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        String p2 = array[array.length -2 - i][array.length -counter + i];
        array2[mb+array.length -1][i] = p2;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are errors here right? Or I misunderstood something, like `String p2 = array ...` should be array2 since the original is 1D

Comment: @LuisArmando this works after the intermediate step :) so array is actual the intermediate step-created array

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all: You can't print a triangle like that for every length of an array. Say for example you had that array but missing the last entry; then your triangle would be missing one element at some point. In fact, you can print such a triangle if and only if the number of elements is the square of a natural number; in your example 16 = 4^2. Now, that 4 is also the length of your longest row.

OK, now how to do it. If you look at the intermediate step

```
9 6 5 2
1 2 6 3
2 7 3 8
1 5 4 7
```

and call that `arr2`, you want to print `arr2[0][0]` in the first row, `arr2[1][0]` and `arr2[0][1]` in the second row and so on until row 4 (which is of course the root of the length of the initial array). So you can write a nested loop that counts up like that.

Then you want to print `arr2[1][3]`, `arr2[2][2]` and `arr2[3][1]` in the next row, then `arr2[2][3]` an `arr2[3][2]` and finally in the last row just `arr2[3][3]`. That is most easily done in a second nested loop.

I won't give you the exact code of course as this is obviously a learning task. But I will tell you that if you have a counter `i` for the outer loops and a counter `j` for the inner ones, the indexes in the intermediate array will depend on both `i` and `j`.

Comment: I get what you're saying my question would be, how would you move between say printing the 6 which is on arr[1] and then the 1 which is in arr[4] to then go back to the 5 in arr[2]. Given that the final print is:

...
6 1
5 ...

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood the question. Anyway, I've edited my answer and now it should hopefully help you solve your task. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well lets think you have two-dimensional array (you can change your one-dimension to two-dimensional easily)
PseudoCode :

```
whereToGo = RIGHT;
i = 0;
j = 0;

maxX = WIDTH;
maxY = HEIGHT;
minX = 0;
minY = 0;

while (somethingLeft){
  addNumberToPyramid(array[i][j]);
  if (whereToGo == RIGHT){
    i++;
    if (maxX == i) {
      whereToGo = DOWN;
      minY++;
    }
  } else if (whereToGo == DOWN){
    //Same as if you go RIGHT, but increasing "j", at the end, you decrease maxY and then goLeft
  } //... other two directions
}
```

This is how to parse input. Similar way for adding it to pyramid. I would prefer creating another 2D array, put that directly there as pyramid and then write method for printing this array correctly :

```
public class Pyramid{
  //initialize minX, maxX etc.
  int[][] array;
  whereToGo = DOWN;
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  //initialize array size in constructor

  public void addNumberToPyramid(int value){
    if (whereToGo == DOWN){
      array[i][j] == value;
      j++;
      if (j == maxY){
        whereToGo = UPRIGHT;
        maxY -= 2;
      } else if (whereToGo == UPRIGHT){
      } //... other else if directions
    }    
  }
}
```